# Grails 2.4.3 ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener

Tags: grails, saml-2.0, grails-plugin, beancreationexception, grails-resources-plugin

I am getting following error when I execute grails run-app, I am trying to run [grails-sso-sample](https://github.com/fuxiaoalex/grails-sso-sample) application locally but unable to do so

Following is the error from Stacktrace

### Stacktrace

```
| Error 2017-01-19 15:06:29,946 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table account_role drop constraint FK_p2jpuvn8yll7x96rae4hvw3sj if exists
| Error 2017-01-19 15:06:29,966 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Table "ACCOUNT_ROLE" not found; SQL statement:
alter table account_role drop constraint FK_p2jpuvn8yll7x96rae4hvw3sj if exists [42102-176]
| Error 2017-01-19 15:06:29,967 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table account_role drop constraint FK_ibmw1g5w37bmuh5fc0db7wn10 if exists
| Error 2017-01-19 15:06:29,967 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Table "ACCOUNT_ROLE" not found; SQL statement:
alter table account_role drop constraint FK_ibmw1g5w37bmuh5fc0db7wn10 if exists [42102-176]
| Error 2017-01-19 15:06:32,648 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'samlIDPDiscovery': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery.setSamlEntryPoint(org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'samlEntryPoint': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.setWebSSOprofile(org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfile); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSSOprofile': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.saml.websso.AbstractProfileBase.setProcessor(org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessor); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processor' defined in class path resource [security/springSecuritySamlBeans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'postBinding' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postBinding': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'velocityEngine' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'velocityEngine': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public static org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory.getEngine()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties
Message: Error creating bean with name 'samlIDPDiscovery': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery.setSamlEntryPoint(org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'samlEntryPoint': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.setWebSSOprofile(org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfile); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSSOprofile': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.saml.websso.AbstractProfileBase.setProcessor(org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessor); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processor' defined in class path resource [security/springSecuritySamlBeans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'postBinding' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postBinding': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'velocityEngine' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'velocityEngine': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public static org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory.getEngine()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties
    Line | Method
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery.setSamlEntryPoint(org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'samlEntryPoint': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.setWebSSOprofile(org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfile); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSSOprofile': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.saml.websso.AbstractProfileBase.setProcessor(org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessor); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processor' defined in class path resource [security/springSecuritySamlBeans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'postBinding' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postBinding': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'velocityEngine' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'velocityEngine': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public static org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory.getEngine()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'samlEntryPoint': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.setWebSSOprofile(org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfile); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSSOprofile': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.saml.websso.AbstractProfileBase.setProcessor(org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessor); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processor' defined in class path resource [security/springSecuritySamlBeans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'postBinding' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postBinding': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'velocityEngine' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'velocityEngine': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public static org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory.getEngine()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.setWebSSOprofile(org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfile); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSSOprofile': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.saml.websso.AbstractProfileBase.setProcessor(org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessor); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processor' defined in class path resource [security/springSecuritySamlBeans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'postBinding' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postBinding': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'velocityEngine' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'velocityEngine': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public static org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory.getEngine()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSSOprofile': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.saml.websso.AbstractProfileBase.setProcessor(org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessor); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processor' defined in class path resource [security/springSecuritySamlBeans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'postBinding' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postBinding': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'velocityEngine' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'velocityEngine': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public static org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory.getEngine()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.saml.websso.AbstractProfileBase.setProcessor(org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessor); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processor' defined in class path resource [security/springSecuritySamlBeans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'postBinding' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postBinding': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'velocityEngine' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'velocityEngine': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public static org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory.getEngine()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processor' defined in class path resource [security/springSecuritySamlBeans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'postBinding' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postBinding': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'velocityEngine' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'velocityEngine': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public static org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory.getEngine()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postBinding': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'velocityEngine' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'velocityEngine': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public static org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory.getEngine()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'velocityEngine': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public static org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory.getEngine()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public static org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory.getEngine()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties
->>  183 | <init>    in org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     60 | <init>    in org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine
|    266 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties
->>  372 | run       in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    361 | run       in     ''
|    360 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    424 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    183 | <init> .  in org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance
|     60 | <init>    in org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine
|    266 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Following is my BuildConfig file

### BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"
        mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
        mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/"
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.24'
        compile('commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1') {
            excludes 'commons-codec', 'commons-logging', 'junit'
        }

        compile('ca.juliusdavies:not-yet-commons-ssl:0.3.9') {
            excludes 'commons-httpclient', 'log4j'
        }

        compile('org.opensaml:opensaml:2.6.1') {
            excludes 'commons-codec', 'commons-collections', 'commons-lang', 'esapi', 'jcip-annotations', 'jcl-over-slf4j', 'joda-time', 'jul-to-slf4j', 'junit', 'log4j-over-slf4j', 'logback-classic', 'openws', 'serializer', 'servlet-api', 'slf4j-api', 'spring-core', 'spring-mock', 'testng', 'velocity', 'xalan', 'xercesImpl', 'xml-apis', 'xml-resolver', 'xmlunit'
        }

        compile('org.opensaml:xmltooling:1.3.4') {
            excludes 'bcprov-jdk15', 'commons-codec', 'jcip-annotations', 'jcl-over-slf4j', 'joda-time', 'jul-to-slf4j', 'junit', 'log4j-over-slf4j', 'logback-classic', 'not-yet-commons-ssl', 'serializer', 'slf4j-api', 'testng', 'xalan', 'xercesImpl', 'xml-apis', 'xml-resolver', 'xmlsec', 'xmlunit'
        }

        compile('org.apache.velocity:velocity:1.7') {
            excludes 'ant', 'commons-collections', 'commons-lang', 'commons-logging', 'hsqldb', 'jdom', 'junit', 'log4j', 'logkit', 'oro', 'servlet-api', 'werken-xpath'
        }

        compile 'joda-time:joda-time:1.6.2'

        compile('org.opensaml:openws:1.4.4') {
            excludes 'commons-codec', 'commons-httpclient', 'jcip-annotations', 'jcl-over-slf4j', 'joda-time', 'jul-to-slf4j', 'junit', 'log4j-over-slf4j', 'logback-classic', 'serializer', 'servlet-api', 'slf4j-api', 'spring-core', 'spring-mock', 'testng', 'xalan', 'xercesImpl', 'xml-apis', 'xml-resolver', 'xmltooling', 'xmlunit'
        }

        compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:1.45'

        compile 'org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:1.4.4'

        compile('org.owasp.esapi:esapi:2.0.1') {
            excludes 'antisamy', 'bsh-core', 'commons-beanutils-core', 'commons-collections', 'commons-configuration', 'commons-fileupload', 'commons-io', 'jsp-api', 'junit', 'log4j', 'servlet-api', 'xom'
        }

        compile('org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.2.RELEASE') {
            export = false
            excludes 'spring-security-core'
            excludes 'spring-security-web'
        }
    }

    plugins {

        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.47"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.0"
        //compile ':cache:1.1.1'
        //compile 'org.grails.plugins:cache-headers:1.1.7'
        compile ':asset-pipeline:1.8.3'
        compile ":spring-security-core:2.0.0"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ':hibernate4:4.3.5.2' // or ':hibernate:3.6.10.14'
        runtime ':database-migration:1.4.0'
        runtime ':jquery:1.11.0.2'
        runtime ':resources:1.2.14'
        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0.1"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.1"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"
    }
}
```

I can provide more details if you want, can anyone help why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because of `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties`. And in your dependencies section you are excluding `'commons-collections'`. Make sure you have the correct version of `'commons-collections'` in your project. In version 4 there isn't a ExtendedProperties class.

Comment: great :)
Thanks @sandeep-poonia this solved my problem.
I added `compile 'commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1` in dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy file and this solved my problem :)